# How to handle empty values in config.ini file in python

Tags: python, ini

I have created one config file having values from an excel sheet.
some values are in integer and some values are empty . how should I handle the empty values ?
for example :-

```
DATE   =
DATE_1 = 0
DATE_2 = 11
DATE_3 = 15
```

here DATE  is empty , how should I handle empty values so that I can use DATE in my python3 script.

Comment: Don't add empty values to the config file?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587041/how-to-handle-empty-values-in-config-files-with-configparser

Comment: How do you handle normal cases, where there is no value? It helps to show an example of what you've tried, so we can better understand the issue you're facing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.